# Redshift performs FETCH ALL when prompted NEXT

Tags: amazon-redshift, sql-workbench-j

While using SQL Workbench/j I noticed odd behaviour on a single-node Redshift's (`dc2.large`;`nodes: 1`) end.

When running below procedure with `FETCH NEXT` (which is is a [must for single nodes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/fetch.html)) I'm still getting an error...

`FORWARD 1` and `FORWARD 0` also didn't help...

> ERROR: Fetch ALL is not supported on single-node clusters. Please
> specify the fetch size (maximum 1000 for single-node clusters) or
> upgrade to a multi node installation.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.sp_proc_with_in_var_two (f1 VARCHAR, rs_out INOUT refcursor)
AS
$$ BEGIN
    RAISE INFO 'f1 = %',f1;
    OPEN rs_out FOR SELECT f1 as v;
   END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
/

BEGIN;

CALL public.sp_proc_with_in_var_two('my_val_to_show','mycur');
FETCH NEXT 1 FROM mycur;

COMMIT;
```

**My setup**:

[image]
[image]

Comment: What does FETCH FORWARD 1; result in?

Comment: Same error with `FORWARD 1`